# How can I search all of the databases on my mysql server for a single string of information

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have around 150 different databases, with dozens of tables each on one of my servers.  I am looking to see which database contains a specific person's name.  Right now, i'm using phpmyadmin to search each database indvidually, but I would really like to be able to search all databases and all tables at once.  Is this possible?  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to use the `information_schema` database, to list all database, all tables, all fields, and loop over all that...

There is this script that could help for at least some part of the work : [anywhereindb](http://code.google.com/p/anywhereindb/) *(quoting)* :

> This code is search all the tables and
>   all the rows and columns in a MYSQL
>   Database. The code is written in PHP.
>   For faster result, we are only
>   searching in the varchar field.

But, as Harmen noted, this only works with one database -- which means you'd have to wrap something arround it, to loop over each database on your server.

For more informations about that, take a look at [Chapter 19. INFORMATION_SCHEMA  Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) ; especially, the [`SCHEMATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/schemata-table.html) table, which contains the name of all databases on the server.

Here's another solution, based on a stored procedure -- which means less client/server calls, which might make it faster : http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/miscpages/mysql-search-through-all-database-tables-columns-stored-procedure.php

Comment: 150 different databases != 150 different tables. Anywhereindb can only search in one database

Comment: Humph ; true :-( I'll edit my post to add a couple of words about that ; thank for the comment !

Answer (score 0):

The right way to go about it would be to NORMALIZE your data in the first place!!!

You say name - but most people have at least 2 names (a surname and a forename) are these split up or in the same field? If they are in the same field, then what order do they appear in? how are they capitalized?

The most efficient way to try to identify where the data might be would be to write a program in C which sifts the raw data files (while the DBMS is shut down) looking for the data - but that will only tell you what table they apppear in.

Failing that you need to write some PHP which iterates through each database ('SHOW databases' works much like a select statement), then iterates through each table in the database, then generates a SELECT statement filtering on each CHAR or VARCHAR column large enough to hold the name you are looking for (try running 'DESC $table').

Good luck.

C.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer probably depends on how often you want to do this. If it is ad-hoc once a week type stuff then the above answers are good.

If you want to do this kind of search once a second, maybe create a "data warehouse" database that contains just the table:columns you want to search (heavily indexed, with a reference back to the source database if that is needed) populated by cron job or by stored procedures driven by changes in the 150 databases...